# vSphere P2V Conversion without converting an iSCSI disk

Tags: vmware-vsphere, iscsi, physical-to-virtual

I have a physical Windows 2008 R2 server that connects via iSCSI, over ethernet, to a SAN. I need to convert the server to virtual, but I **don't** want to convert the iSCSI volume to VMDK, because I don't have the storage space required.

Rather, I'd like to leave the iSCSI connection intact and have the new VM continue to use the SAN. The VMs on my vSphere host are not being stored on the SAN (they're on local storage), and everything is on the same LAN.

Can I do this? When using vSphere P2V Converter, would I simply uncheck the box to convert the iSCSI volume? Will the iSCSI connection carry over to the VM and continue to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select to not convert that disk in the converter, as simple as that. The iSCSI connection will be usable in the VM and the settings will follow the P2V.

but, IMO, I would recommand to not use an iSCSI disk inside a VM. To be sure before please validate, as when in a VM if the storage is in a iSCSI the quiesce method for snapshot does not work usually.

> Virtual machines with independent disks must be powered off before you
>   take a snapshot. Snapshots of powered-on or suspended virtual machines
>   with independent disks are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You don't convert iSCSI disk -> VMDK (in reality it won't even work), rather you allow converted OS to maintain TCP (...and iSCSI) connectivity.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc%2FGUID-AC22728E-B1B2-48FA-A6D6-62C0045C665F.html

Plus, it's a good idea to allow OS to manage your iSCSI connection, in-guest iSCSI is always slow.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/650986-what-is-the-best-place-to-attach-iscsi-esxi-host-or-vm